# Sum of many column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function that help me to find sum of two rows and get output of total cost So again I want to get sum of the output(total cost).

```
public function getUsageData(Request $request)
{
    $start_date = $request->get('start_date');
    $end_date = $request->get('end_date');
    $particulars =DB::table('particulars')
        ->join('reqs', 'particulars.particular_id', "=", 'reqs.particular_id')
        ->whereBetween('date_issued', [$start_date, $end_date])
        ->select('particulars.item_name','particulars.unit','particulars.price','reqs.quantity_issued',
            DB::raw('sum(particulars.price*reqs.quantity_issued)AS total_cost'))
        ->groupBy('particulars.particular_id')
        ->get();       
}
```

I get sum of two row that form `Total` cost. I want to get sum of total cost column at the bottom so as to make it easy to understand for user without calculating it.

Comment: Your result should only have one row with the total cost?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code else share the table structure please**

```
$particulars =DB::table('particulars as A')
    ->leftjoin('reqs as B', function ($join) {
        $join->on('A.particular_id', '=', 'B.particular_id');
    })
    ->whereBetween('A.date_issued', [$start_date, $end_date]) // i have taken date issued from table particulars as you have not mentioned else you can change A.date_issued as B.date_issued .
    ->select('A.item_name','A.unit','A.price','B.quantity_issued',DB::raw('sum(A.price*B.quantity_issued) as total_cost'))
    ->groupBy('A.particular_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but I want sum of price and quantity(total cost) to sum the total

Comment: the sum I got that  is total cost like this totol cost(100,200,400,500) in the table so I want to sum those 4 value

Comment: I want sum of new generated column